# Deleting MySQL Records Based on a Number

Tags: php, mysql, .net, asp-classic

I'm using `MySQL 5.5.` I need to delete records that are higher then 180 from the table and rather then having to do a loop through all records and delete one at a time I wanted to know is there a way to give MySQL a delete command with any field Slide value of 181 or greater?

For example:

```
conn.execute "DELETE FROM " & CONN_DATABASENAME & ".tbl_course_progress WHERE slide=>'181' AND aid='2'")) & "';"
```

Thanks,

Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much have it right there

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE slide >= 181;
```

---

Here's a very trivial way to do it in PHP

```
$slide_id = 181;
$query    = sprintf("DELETE FROM table WHERE slide >= %d", $slide_id);

mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: I had a funny feeling it could be done but wasn't sure. Thanks for confirming it for me!